# MSbuild built in variables

Tags: msbuild

Could someone translate this, into a syntax that uses the built in variables?

```
\\myserver\builds\mybuild\Daily_20090525.1\Release\_PublishedWebsites\myWebsite
```

it should be something like:

```
$(DropLocation)\mybuild\$(?...)\Release\_PublishedWebsites\myWebsite
```

Comment: This may help you...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/0fb8d97d-513e-4d37-8528-52973f65a034 or this one may help:
http://en.csharp-online.net/MSBuild:_By_Example—Using_Environment_Variables_in_Your_Project Two different ways of achieving what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might help:
substitute "mybuild\$(?...)" with "$(BuildNumber)"

I had a similar problem where I was trying to copy from the drop location to a "Latest" folder. I found that to construct the final destination of the files (\MyServer\MyShare\builds\MyBuild\Daily_20090708.14\Mixed Platforms\Release) translated to the following using variables: 
$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.PlatformToBuild)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)

I also found it helpful to use the Message task for troubleshooting. The following task will tell you what the variable translate to. 
`<Message Text="$(DropLocation)\$(BuildNumber)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.PlatformToBuild)\%(ConfigurationToBuild.FlavorToBuild)\"/>`
To see the output, look in BuildLog.txt.

PS: My tasks that used the properties and items mentioned above where located inside `<Target Name="AfterDropBuild">`.